# If engineers were to create an entirely new human species, what factors would they consider?

Tags: evolution, engineering, species

Say engineers wanted to create a new human species that is perfectly suited to the environmental and seasonal changes of the current world: What features would they consider?

The new species is also not supposed to undergo the process of evolution (if that is possible). It also has to reproduce offspring that doesn't look like each other.

Comment: You let people engineer people, and [this](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2012-04-18) will happen.

Comment: "perfectly suited for environmental and seasonal changes of the current world"... which environment? This world has climate zones ranging from arctic to tropic to deserts.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I am not sure what you mean with "no supposed to undergo the process of evolution". Do you mean that they shoul produce exact duplicates when birthing offspring? How would they adapt in such a case to differences in the environment over a longer timespan? At the same time you want offspring that doesn't look like each other. Does that mean the children have to have different looks from their parents? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: And by the way: humans are a species. "new human species" is an oxymoron. Maybe you mean "new humanoid species"? As in, they sort of resemble humans, but their genetic differences are too large to procreate with them.

Comment: What level of detail do you expect from an answer? From broad descriptions like what  we can find in your 2nd paragraph to biochemical details - Please specify. I think this is an interesting question, but it is important to make it clear what you want from an answer. Could you perhaps explain what you even mean by factor?

Comment: @Philipp to be suited in all sorts of environments, whether arctic or tropical.

Comment: @Raditz_35 details like the amount of fat, far, body size etc. that the creature has to have to be better suited than any human alive. In other words, what evolution could not optimize.

Comment: @Philipp you can call it a human subspecies

Comment: The amount of fat? You need to explain that one because that depends on how much you eat basically and doesn't need to be designed.

Comment: *Not supposed to undergo the process of evolution* means "not alive". Natural evolution is an intrinsic property of a living population.

Comment: @AlexP We are all part of a living population. When did you last evolve intrinsically? :) Sorry I couldn't help myself. Your comment was the perfect set-up for a joke.

Comment: Am I right in presuming that by "not supposed to undergo the process of evolution" means this human species is engineered and doesn't arise through evolution?

Comment: @a4android: I a member of a population but I am not a population. It is populations which evolve (biologically), not individuals. I do hope that I am still evolving mentally. Participating on this site helps.

Comment: @AlexP More so than you think. We are all populations of cells and bacteria. Actually we have more bacteria than cells. If those little rascals are evolving, we may be considered to be evolving too. Yes I have done courses in evolutionary biology. I do know it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can not have environmental adaption if you do not have a specific environment

Humans are the **only** animal that can be found all over the world. In every climate zone imaginable. Is it because of our great adaptions to environments? **No.**

We are very poorly adapted to any specific environment. Set a naked man out in the desert, he dies. Set him out naked in the arctic, he dies. Set him out in the rainforest and something is likely to kill him.

The reason we are found everywhere is that we **adapt our environment instead of adapting to it**. We have clothes and houses to shield us from immediate weather conditions. We have cleaned most of our environments of predators that could harm us.
That is why we developed technology.

Humanity's greatest adaption is the intelligence and the power to craft tools for any kind of purpose. That is why as a species we are poorly adapted physically, because we use technology to make up for our weaknesses and become better at doing certain things than even some animals who specialise in those things.

---

**Note:**
If you are asking what to change so they are better adapted to a specific climate and enviroment then you need to state what climate that would be. Otherwise no one could ever list all possibilities.

Comment: Theres actually a ton of adaptations to be found within the human species. And while we have used technology to do most of what you say, most of the "accompmishments" like dealing with predators are pretty recent.

Answer (score 0):

The features seem simple. When talking about environment and survival there's just 3 things: sex, shelter, food. Where "sex" contains everything from looking good to attract a mate to raising your children, shelter would now only be about the body providing protection from the elements and food be about making sure you can gather, eat and perhaps more importantly drink anywhere on earth.

So the features are:
- easily and safely giving birth
- efficiënt with food, so low metabolisms overall
- a large focus on the stomach and intestinal tract to give as large a selection of things to eat and deal with the waste safely.
- Skin, skin, skin. It needs to be protected against light, but more importantly be adaptive to either insulate the body in cold area's and rapidly cool the body in hot area's. Additionally it still needs to protect the body against damage, intruders like bacteria and fungi and be easily repairable when it does get damaged. This is in all likelyhood the biggest challenge, and might not be possible until you get to work on something like my super-soldier questions but at that point you creating biological robots rather than humans.